# I want to see "redirecting you to the login page" when a user successfully registers on my website. How can i do this?

Tags: php, redirect, database-connection

This is a php question. Here's my code for inserting data into my database:

```
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if(!$con){
die('Could not connect:' .mysql_error());
}

echo "Connected successfully.";

$database=mysql_select_db('90210store');

if(!$database){
die('<br>Could not select database:' .mysql_error());
}

echo "<br>Database successfully selected";

$FirstName=$_POST['FirstName']; //to get the information written in the form
$LastName=$_POST['LastName'];
$EmailAdd=$_POST['EmailAdd'];
$check_list=$_POST['check_list'];
$dob=$_POST['dob'];
$Gender=$_POST['gender'];
$Password=$_POST['Password'];

$first= "INSERT INTO login
(FirstName,LastName,EmailAdd,Newsletter,DOB,Gender,Password)
VALUES ('$FirstName','$LastName','$EmailAdd','$check_list','$dob','$Gender','$Password')";

$result=mysql_query($first);

if($result){
echo('<br>Data entered successfully');
}

else{
echo('<br>Fail');
}


if($result)
{
header('Location: phpredirectlogin.php');
}
mysql_close($con);

?>
```

I tried to redirect the user to the page phpredirectlogin.php so as to have "redirecting you to the login page" written on the page and then redirecting him to the login page but i'm not being able to find a way to do it. Here's the code for the phpredirectlogin.php page:

```
<?
echo ('Redirecting you to the login page');

header('Location:account.html');

?>
```

It redirects the user to the login page directly without showing "redirecting you to the login page". Can someone tell me how to do this? Thank you and sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**That is not possible** ..

You cannot display something and do a redirect at the same time , you will only be redirected and you will not be able to see that message.

You can use native Javascript alert with its redirect.

```
<?php
echo "<script>alert('Redirecting you to the login page');</script>";
echo "<script>window.location = 'account.html';</script>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @ShankarDamodaran has said, you need to use of something more in PHP. But you can also make use of this HTML tag where you can specify the time duration before it redirects:

`echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3; url=phpredirectlogin.php">';`

The number `3` above specifies the page should be redirected after 3 seconds.

Comment: Wow i didn't know this could be done. I learned something new. I'll try it thank you.